# The Aspnet.core program logs in but considers the data in the same table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I'm having a problem with the code, the program logs in and out
I have three controllers for each type of user, when I log in the program logs in but the presentation is as if they were all from the Socio table.
I already checked the tables and don't have the same data and I checked the layout of the views for each type of user and everything is fine.
Can someone help me fix this please?

The login method is in the controller home, and this is the code:

```
 public IActionResult Login(string user, string password, string? ReturnUrl)
        {
            SHA512 sha512 = SHA512Managed.Create();
            byte[] bytes = sha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(password));


            string passHash = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

            Socios socio = _context.Socios.Include(s => s.Gerir).Include(s => s.Mensagem).Include(s => s.Participa).Include(s => s.PersonalTrainer).Include(s => s.Peso).Include(s => s.PlanosExercicios).FirstOrDefault(s => s.NomeUtilizador == user && s.Password == password);
            if (socio != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Nome", socio.NomeUtilizador);
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", socio.Idsocio);

                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Perfil", "Socio");

            }
            Professores prof = _context.Professores.Include(p => p.MapaAulasGrupo).Include(p => p.Mensagem).Include(p => p.Peso).Include(s => s.PersonalTrainer).Include(p => p.PlanosExercicios).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Nome == user && p.Password == password);
            if (prof != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Nome", prof.Nome);
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", prof.Idprofessor);


                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Perfil", "Professor");

            }
            Administrador admin = _context.Administrador.Include(a => a.Gerir).SingleOrDefault(a => a.Nome == user && a.Password == password);
            if (admin != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Nome", admin.Nome);
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", admin.Idadministrador);


                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Perfil", "Administrador");

            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
            {
                //ModelState.AddModelError("","Utilizador inexistente na base de dados!");
                //TempData["mensagemErro"] = "Utilizador inexistente na base de dados!";
                //return View("NaoEncontrado","Socios");
                return LocalRedirect("/");
            }
            else
            {
                return LocalRedirect(ReturnUrl);
            }
        }
```

In the layout I have to differentiate the type of logins, presenting views corresponding to each controller

```
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-dark border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"> </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        @if (SociosController.estaAutenticado(Context))
                        {

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-controller="Socios" asp-action="PerfilSocio">Meu perfil</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-controller="Socios" asp-action="ListarProfessores">Professores</a>

                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <p class="nav-link text-white">Bem-vindo, @Context.Session.GetString("Nome")</p>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <form class="form-inline" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Logout">
                                    <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-white">Sair</button>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        }

                        else if (ProfessoresController.estaAutenticado(Context))
                        {
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-controller="Professores" asp-action="Perfil">Meu perfil</a>

                            </li>


                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <p class="nav-link text-white">Bem-vindo, @Context.Session.GetString("Nome")</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <form class="form-inline" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Logout">
                                    <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-white">Sair</button>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        }

                        else if (AdministradoresController.estaAutenticado(Context))
                        {

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-controller="Administradores" asp-action="Perfil">Meu perfil</a>

                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <p class="nav-link text-white">Bem-vindo, @Context.Session.GetString("Nome")</p>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <form class="form-inline" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Logout">
                                    <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-white">Sair</button>
                                </form>
                            </li>

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Login">Entrar </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Registo">Registar</a>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Pagina Inicial</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Info">Sobre nós</a>
                        </li>


                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AulasDeGrupo">Aulas de Grupo</a>
                        </li>




                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

The function that calls in the layout "estaAutenticado"
is found in the Controllers of each type of user and this is the code:

```
public static bool estaAutenticado(HttpContext contexto)
        {
            if (contexto.Session.GetInt32("UserId") != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Can someone help me fix this? I don’t understand why he considers all users I log in as a Partner, even if they’re from the Teacher or Administrator tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you set the same Session-key `UserId` for each type of user , you should make the modification like below:

*Login method*

```
Socios socio = _context.Socios.Include(s => s.Gerir).Include(s => s.Mensagem).Include(s => s.Participa).Include(s => s.PersonalTrainer).Include(s => s.Peso).Include(s => s.PlanosExercicios).FirstOrDefault(s => s.NomeUtilizador == user && s.Password == password);
        if (socio != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Nome", socio.NomeUtilizador);
            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", socio.Idsocio);

            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Perfil", "Socio");

        }
        Professores prof = _context.Professores.Include(p => p.MapaAulasGrupo).Include(p => p.Mensagem).Include(p => p.Peso).Include(s => s.PersonalTrainer).Include(p => p.PlanosExercicios).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Nome == user && p.Password == password);
        if (prof != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Nome", prof.Nome);
            //set ProfessorId for Professores 
            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("ProfessorId", prof.Idprofessor);
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Perfil", "Professor");

        }
        Administrador admin = _context.Administrador.Include(a => a.Gerir).SingleOrDefault(a => a.Nome == user && a.Password == password);
        if (admin != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Nome", admin.Nome);

            //set AdminId for Administrador 
            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("AdminId", admin.Idadministrador);
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Perfil", "Administrador");

        }
```

*estaAutenticado method in each type Controller*

```
//SociosController
public static bool estaAutenticado(HttpContext context)
{
        if (context.Session.GetInt32("UserId") != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}

//ProfessoresController
public static bool estaAutenticado(HttpContext context)
{
        if (context.Session.GetInt32("ProfessorId") != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}

//AdministradoresController
public static bool estaAutenticado(HttpContext context)
{
        if (context.Session.GetInt32("AdminId") != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```